# consulta en LINQ, select con diferentes tablas

Tags: c#, linq, select

ven este metodo, hago la repetición de `(from Proyectos in db.Proyectos select Proyectos.idProyecto).Max();`

no me gusta, quiero en `var db`, sacar el nombre de la tabla, esta tabla anteriormente ya se le había hecho una inserción y en este metodo quiero traer el ultimo id, que es el que se ha insertado (Punto 2), estoy abierto a cualquier otra idea que me ayude a mejorar este codigo

```
private long retornaUltimoIdInsertado(string nomTabla)
            {
                long ultimoId = 0;
                var db = new AdminProyectosContext(); 

            if (nomTabla == "Proyecto")
            { 
                ultimoId  =  (from Proyectos in db.Proyectos select Proyectos.idProyecto).Max();
            }
            if (nomTabla == "Actividades")
            {
                ultimoId = (from Actividades in db.Actividades select Actividades.idActividad).Max();
            }

            if (nomTabla == "Bitacora")
            {
                ultimoId = (from Bitacora in db.Bitacora select Bitacora.idBitacora).Max();
            }
            return ultimoId;
        }
```

Punto 2:

```
  public void TomarValoresIdTablaPrincipal(long[] arrValoIdEliminar, string nomTabla)
        {
            long idFiltrar = 0;
            if (operacion.ToString() ==  estados.Insertar.ToString())
            {
                Proyectos.idProyecto).Max();
                idFiltrar = retornaUltimoIdInsertado(nomTabla);
                BusquedaCamposTabla(idFiltrar);

             }
}
```

Aqui comienza todo, se realiza la inserción

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AuthMVCJWT(Roles = "Administrador")]
        public ActionResult AgregarProyecto(Proyectos Proyecto)
        {
            if (Proyecto == null) {
                return new JsonNetResult("Error, no se recibieron datos");
            }

            var db = new AdminProyectosContext();
            var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name);
            Proyecto.idUsuarioRegistra = usuario.IdUsuario;
            Proyecto.idUsuarioActualiza = usuario.IdUsuario;
            Proyecto.fechaRegistro = DateTime.Now;
            Proyecto.fechaActualizacion = Proyecto.fechaRegistro;
            db.Proyectos.Add(Proyecto);
            db.SaveChanges();

            long[] vacio = new long[]{};
            operacion = estados.Insertar;


            TomarValoresIdTablaPrincipal(vacio,"Proyecto");

            return new JsonNetResult(new { msg = "Guardado exitoso" });
        }
```

Saludos, cualquier cosa estare al pendiente.

Comment: Es eso entity framework ?

Comment: Contextualiza bien lo que quieres realizar y el problema que tienes... no sirve que publiques código sin explicar COHERENTEMENTE lo que estas tratando de hacer

Comment: Si Juan Salvador Portugal

Comment: Gracias  Paulo Urbano Rivera, tomare en cuenta tu comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que estás usando Entity Framework y el Id de la tabla es autoincrementado (IDENTITY), no necesitas hacer un segundo query (que de paso tiene un bug sutil) para obtener el último Id insertado, Entity Framework ya te lo devuelve.  En tu ejemplo:

```
public ActionResult AgregarProyecto(Proyectos Proyecto)
{
    // ...
    db.Proyectos.Add(Proyecto);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // En este punto, luego de SaveChanges el objeto proyecto ya tiene el nuevo Id

    Proyecto.idProyecto // aquí deberías tener el último Id para que lo uses

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ya probé el código, que me diste. jalo muchísimas gracias andamos nuevos en  esto. Gracias por la ayuda